# Fetch default UserAgent in windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone, user-agent, system.net.httpwebrequest

Is there a way to fetch the default useragent string from HttpClient or from a HttpRequestMessage.Headers?

Or is it only possible by using a Webview class object?

Comment: Yep, `WebView` may be the only way to get the `User-Agent`: http://www.michielpost.nl/PostDetail_74.aspx

Comment: I have method one of my web services you can call to get the user agent.  https://kentuckerapps.azurewebsites.net/api/useragent